# MenuItem event wasn't triggered in asp.net menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

The menu item click event was failed to trigger code behind event method when click the menu item. I added the OnMenuItemClick(Menu_Item_Click) at menu even though it was getting failed to trigger the code behind event.

How can i sort it out this issue?

/** Asp.net Template code goes here **/

```
     <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
            EnableViewState="True" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" 
            BackColor="#F7F6F3" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
            Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#7C6F57" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" OnMenuItemClick="Menu_Item_Click">

<Items>
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"  Text="Default">
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Search.aspx" Text="Search">
</Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Codebehind Code Goes here

```
protected void Menu_Item_Click ( object sender, MenuEventArgs e )
{
   /** Some Validation goes here **/
}
```

Comment: Can we see how you have defined your manu items in asp ?

Comment: Check the updated code now

Comment: Still i dont see the menu items in the asp template

Comment: I hope you can able to view now

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced this problem.
I solved it by eliminating the field NavigateUrl.
If you eliminate this field then the click event will be triggered.
In the function(event handler function) you can use the following code to navigate to the necessary page using the following code.

```
protected void MainMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    /*your necessary code*/
    Response.Redirect(((Menu)sender).SelectedItem.Target);

}
```

In the above code **TargetField** is specified in the Menu tag with the necessary address.

or you can specify the address directly by.

```
protected void MainMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    /*your necessary code*/
    Response.Redirect("Page.aspx");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code and description ,for my experience the issue is related to the text and the value properties of menuitem are not specified.

Ex:

```
 <asp:Menu runat="server" ID="MainMenuCtl" BorderWidth="0"
            Orientation="Vertical" onmenuitemclick="MainMenuCtl_MenuItemClick">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~\App_Themes/SiteDefault/Images/Mediabutton.png" value="&nbsp;" ToolTip="Media Clips">
                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~\App_Themes/SiteDefault/Images/CalendarButton.png" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;" ToolTip="View calendar of events">
                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~\App_Themes/SiteDefault/Images/PoetryButtonReg.png" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" ToolTip="Poetry">
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Still I'm facing the same problem after changing likewise

Comment: Can you add value attribute as well ?

Comment: i added value along with NavigateURL